# css how to use width:fit-content with dynamic font?

Tags: html, css

consider this div element :

```
    <div style="
            text-align      : center;
            font-size       : min(calc(var(--fp-title-font-ratio-h) *100vh),calc(var(--fp-title-font-ratio-w) *100vw));
            color           : var(--brand-color);
            background      : rgba(0,0,0,0.0);
            margin-top      : 0px;
            z-index         : 500;
            width           : fit-content;
            left            : calc(var(--fp-title-left-ratio-h) * 100vw - (var(--fp-title-left-ratio-w) * 100vw));
            transform       : translateX(0%);
            position        : absolute;
            border-radius   : 10px;
            text-align      : left;
            font-family     : 'Playfair Display', serif;
            text-shadow     : 1px 1px 2px #040b0a,  0 0 0.2em #040b0a;
            ">
        MY TEXT IS VERY LONG ABCDEFGH
    </div>
```

The variables are all defined. When this page loads, then first the div is actually fitting the text. so far so good.

But, the font size is updated after that. I would think that the font size will be calculated *before* the text is rendered, and the div will adjust to it. But, i appears, that the font size is updated *after* the div has stretched.

The problem therefore is: despite using `width:fit-content`, the text is breaking and wraping to a new line. Both in firefox (i also tested with `width:-moz-fit-content`) and chromium.

**Question**

How can I force the div to fit content after font size has been applied by CSS?

NB: The break will be apparent when the width of the screen size is 1920x1080.

**Attempt to solution**

Using `display:inline` or `display:inline-block` has no effect. I know I can resolve this in javascript later, but I prefer a CSS solution without Javascript, please. I do not know if this task is beyond CSS.

Thank you.

Comment: Not sure you can do this with CSS. Once the font has loaded you would need to repaint the page to get the CSS to update.

Answer (score 0):

Don't think this can be done with purely CSS, here is an example with javascript:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Dynamic Width Adjustment</title>
    <style>
        div {
            text-align: center;
            font-size: min(calc(var(--fp-title-font-ratio-h) * 100vh), calc(var(--fp-title-font-ratio-w) * 100vw));
            width: auto; 
            white-space: nowrap; 
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="myDiv">
        MY TEXT IS VERY LONG ABCDEFGH
    </div>

    <script>
        // Get the div element
        const div = document.getElementById("myDiv");

        // Calculate the font size
        const fontSize = Math.min(
            parseFloat(getComputedStyle(div).getPropertyValue("--fp-title-font-ratio-h")) * window.innerHeight,
            parseFloat(getComputedStyle(div).getPropertyValue("--fp-title-font-ratio-w")) * window.innerWidth
        );

        // Set the font size
        div.style.fontSize = fontSize + "px";

        // Update the width to fit the content after setting the font size
        div.style.width = "fit-content";
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```